# C# preprocessor class accessibility

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

I've got a straight forward question about the class accessibility. Is it possible to declare a class as public in debug mode but private in release mode?

The reason is that I would like to be able to use the class with Matlab but as it is deployed to customers, I don't them to be able to access this class.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#if (DEBUG) 
    public 
#endif
    class YourClass {
#if (DEBUG)
        public
#else
        private
#endif
        class NestedClass {
        }
    }
```

Comment: well it should because by default the class is private, but what if I want it to be internal ?

Comment: class is internal by default. There is no private class in namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the class as `internal` and apply the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` to it:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyTestAssembly")]
```

see: [InternalsVisibleToAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) (on MSDN)